# Altium cannot find harness files of design

Tags: pcb, schematics, altium

I downloaded the project source files from the ROACH project: [Link](https://casper.berkeley.edu/wiki/ROACH-2_Revision_2) to it.

I tried importing them in Altium Designer, but it cannot find the harness files, which is strange as they're in the same directory that the PRJPCB file is in.

Has anyone run into this or a similar problem?

Comment: The harness files should be automatically regenerated every time the project is compiled. I suspect that the import-process broke something.

Comment: This is often a symptom of competing harness ports connected together. Can you post more information about the specific error message you're getting?

Comment: When I went to import the project, I got multiple missing harness files and two missing libraries -
keyelco_1065.pcblib
soic8-pp.pcblib
The PCB file for the project exists and looks fine, but the schematics don't have a link to the footprints (I think because those two libraries are missing).

I'm going to ask on the CASPER mailing list and see if they can post those libraries, but if you have suggestions I'm open to them. Thanks @ConnorWolf

Comment: Is this a native Altium project? I thought the ROACH stuff was done with Cadence Allegro. If you're going through the import-wizard in Altium, I think what you've got is about as good as it's ever going to get. PCB file formats don't map perfectly to one-another, and converting is always going to leave some issues you have to resolve manually.

Comment: Roach-2 is native Altium; Roach-1 was Allegro or PADS (I think PADS). Perhaps there is a way to extract the footprints and rebuild the library?

Comment: I just figured out how to do this from http://www.edaboard.com/thread183216.html
...this program is so far ahead of the competition it is a little ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

In Altium 18 and above the Regenerate Harness Definitions has been removed. Further to this, I also think the generation on compile has been removed. The files are generated when a schematic file containing a harness is opened. An easy option is to right click on the containing folder of the schematics in the project window and choose open all. If you open all the schematics at once, all of the harnesses will be generated and your compiler issues should go away

Answer (score 0):

I had sometimes troubbles with harness definitions. If the compile does not do it you can right click on the Project (.prjpcb) and select "Regenerate Harness Definitions" (tested in Altium 16 & 17) 
In the Tools menu there is also the "Harness Definition Problem Finder" which may help you.